# Save the value of the active checkbox when needed in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter. I have a checkbox in the form with inputs and I also created a field in the database for this checkbox.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
            echo form_checkbox(array(
    'name' => 'viber',
    'id' => 'viber',
    'value' => '1',
    'checked' => ( $this->input->post('viber') == 1 )
));?>
```

Now that I keep the form - the checkbox is active, what do I do reloading the page - the checkbox becomes inactive again, how to solve this question?

Comment: <?php
            echo form_checkbox(array(
    'name' => 'viber',
    'id' => 'viber',
    'value' => '1',
   'checked' =>  $this->input->post('viber') ? 'checked':' '));

That's right?
This unfortunately does not work (

Comment: Why do you want to keep the checkbox checked? Is it the default state?

Comment: Could you add the var_dump of $this->input->post('viber') to your question? If you're unsure how to obtain it, simply write:  var_dump($this->input->post('viber'));

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#viber').prop('checked', true);
 //or $('#viber').attr('checked', true);  
}
);
```

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from it - why not use PHP for this?

Comment: because php script run after page reloading but  jquery document ready function load before page loading

Comment: Please add all such explanation to your answer by editing